# Preproccesor macro to

Tags: c, matrix, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

Im trying to create a preprocessor macro to allocate and free memory for matrix/vector of any data type. Here is what I have so far:

```
  #ifndef H_ARRAY_H 
#define H_ARRAY_H

    #include "xmalloc.h" 
    #define make_vector(v,n) (v = xmalloc( (n) * sizeof *(v))
    #define free_vector(v) do { free(v) ; v = NULL; } while(0)
    #define make_matrx(a , m , n) do {                                              \
        size_t make_matrix_loop_counter;                                            \
        make_vector(a, (m) + 1);                                                \
        for ( make_matrix_loop_counter = 0; make_matrix_loop_counter < (m) ; make_matrix_loop_counter++)            \
            make_vector((a)[make_matrix_loop_counter], (n));                                \
        (a)[m] = NULL;                                                      \
    }  while (0)
    #define free_matrix(a) do {                                                     \
        if (a != NULL){                                                     \
            size_t make_matrix_loop_counter;                                        \
            for (make_matrix_loop_counter = 0 ; (a) [make_matrix_loop_counter] != NULL; make_matrix_loop_counter++)     \
                free_vector((a)[make_matrix_loop_counter]); \
        free_vector(a);                                                     \
        a != NULL;                                                      \
        }                                                           \
    } while (0)
```

But when I try to construct a matrix it spits out an error "implicit declaration of function ‘make_matrix’".
Any suggestions.
PS: xmalloc.h allocate space

Comment: You want us to debug your macro?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your MACRO name should read `make_matrx` instead of `make_matrix`?

You need to correct the macro name spelling. Otherwise, when you use `make_matrix()` in your code, it does not find a corresponding *function*.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth One by you, one my me, that's all the two votes currently. :-)